# How to get a good response from saving a model

Tags: backbone.js

With backbone.js I'm saving a model. A PUT is send to the server and the response is returned. The first time I do it, it returns success, the following times an error is return, because after the first time the response is added to the model.

Save function in Backbone.js:

```
saveCountry: function() {
    this.model.save({},{
        success: function(model, response) {
            console.log('success! ' + response);
        },
        error: function(model, response) {
            console.log('error! ' + response);
        }
    });
    this.render();

    return false;
},
```

PHP returns a JSON-string:

```
{"response": "Model saved!"}
```

Following PUT's get an error as response, because 'response' is added to the model:

```
Unknown column 'response' in 'field list'
```

Why is the response added to the model and how do I prevent it?

Comment: Couldn't you just do a conditional and skip the 'response' in your php script?

Comment: I could, but I thought it would be cleaner to let the server side decide the response.

Comment: Nope, I thought it would be cleaner if the response came from PHP (server side), but know, as dira suggests, I'm doing it client side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Backbone's documentation on model `save`:

> Set a hash of model attributes, and sync the model to the server. If
>   the server returns an attributes hash that differs, the model's state
>   will be set again.
>   http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41

What to do to make it work: don't return {"response": "Model saved!"} from the server. Just return a success (status 200) with no content.

If the save did not work, return a JSON with the errors, and Backbone will trigger an error event on your model, with the JSON you provided (see http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41 and http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-145).

Answer (score 7):

Just to resurrect an ancient thread...

It isn't always possible/desirable to change the response you get back from the server.

Another solution is to override [parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) in the model to take care of this. For your situation, where the response is inappropriate for ALL of your models, you could do it in a superclass.

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(data) {
        delete data["success"];
        return data;
    }
});

Address = MyModel.extend({
    saveCountry: function() {
        this.model.save({},{
            success: function(model, response) {
                console.log('success! ' + response);
            },
            error: function(model, response) {
                console.log('error! ' + response);
            }
        });
        this.render();

        return false;
    },

    ...

});
```